# SQL get total sellers of product category

Tags: mysql, sql

I have like this database tables:

**Table** `categories`

```
id
title
description
status
```

**Table** `products`

```
id
user_id
category_id
description
status
```

**Table** `product_varieties`

```
id
variety_id
product_id
description
wholesale_price
retail_price
status
total
```

I have query to get price  `min`, `max` and `avg` in each category:

```
SELECT `categories`.`title`,
         min(product_varieties.wholesale_price) AS wholesalePriceMin,
         max(product_varieties.wholesale_price) AS wholesalePriceMax,
         avg(product_varieties.wholesale_price) AS wholesalePriceAvg,
         min(product_varieties.retail_price) AS retailPriceMin,
         max(product_varieties.retail_price) AS retailPriceMax,
         avg(product_varieties.retail_price) AS retailPriceAvg
FROM `products`
LEFT JOIN `categories`
    ON `categories`.`id` = `products`.`category_id`
LEFT JOIN `product_varieties`
    ON `product_varieties`.`product_id` = `products`.`id`
WHERE `products`.`id` IN (1,2,3,4)
GROUP BY  `products`.`category_id`
```

Now I need get total users (sellers) of each category by editing my current query.

I tried like this:

```
SELECT `categories`.`title`,
         min(product_varieties.wholesale_price) AS wholesalePriceMin,
         max(product_varieties.wholesale_price) AS wholesalePriceMax,
         avg(product_varieties.wholesale_price) AS wholesalePriceAvg,
         min(product_varieties.retail_price) AS retailPriceMin,
         max(product_varieties.retail_price) AS retailPriceMax,
         avg(product_varieties.retail_price) AS retailPriceAvg,
         
    (SELECT user_id,
         COUNT(*)
    FROM products
    GROUP BY  category_id) AS totalUsers
FROM `products`
LEFT JOIN `categories`
    ON `categories`.`id` = `products`.`category_id`
LEFT JOIN `product_varieties`
    ON `product_varieties`.`product_id` = `products`.`id`
WHERE `products`.`id` IN (1,2,3,4)
GROUP BY  `products`.`category_id`
```

But my query not work and return error with message:

```
SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1241 Operand should contain 1 column(s)
```

How I can correct my query?

Comment: Instead LEFT JOIN the totalUsers subquery, Or have a correlated subquery that returns one column, one row.

Comment: Your subquery must be correlated, not complete.

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Comment: Your scheme seems to be wrong. Category and Product with different `user_id` may be reffered via junction table nevertheless.

Comment: `(SELECT user_id,COUNT(*) FROM products GROUP BY  category_id) AS totalUsers` In the given line, you used 2 operand that's why the query showing error. You can use either `Count(*)` or `user_id` else you can write separate subquery for `count` and `user_id`.

Comment: Oh sorry my `categories` table doesn't has `user_id` column. Now I'll edit my question @Akina

Comment: Please replace approx. tables description with their actual CREATE TABLE. Add INSERT INTO with some sample data (5-10 rows enough). Show desired output for this data with explanations (refer to values).

Comment: Sample data is needed. I suggest you read these: [Provide a `Minimal Complete Verifiable Example` (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
and [Why should I provide a MCVE](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "correlated subquery" can be used in the select list of your main query, this query must return just a single value and the "correlation" occurs through the where clause in that some data from the main query is used to locate the wanted data in the subquery.

```
SELECT
      `categories`.`title`
    , min(product_varieties.wholesale_price) AS wholesalePriceMin
    , max(product_varieties.wholesale_price) AS wholesalePriceMax
    , avg(product_varieties.wholesale_price) AS wholesalePriceAvg
    , min(product_varieties.retail_price) AS retailPriceMin
    , max(product_varieties.retail_price) AS retailPriceMax
    , avg(product_varieties.retail_price) AS retailPriceAvg
    , (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM products AS p
        WHERE p.category_id = `products`.`category_id`
        ) AS totalUsers
FROM `products`
LEFT JOIN `categories` ON `categories`.`id` = `products`.`category_id`
LEFT JOIN `product_varieties` ON `product_varieties`.`product_id` = `products`.`id`
WHERE `products`.`id` IN (1, 2, 3, 4)
GROUP BY `products`.`category_id`
```

but I suspect this can be further simplified:

```
SELECT
      `categories`.`title`
    , min(product_varieties.wholesale_price) AS wholesalePriceMin
    , max(product_varieties.wholesale_price) AS wholesalePriceMax
    , avg(product_varieties.wholesale_price) AS wholesalePriceAvg
    , min(product_varieties.retail_price) AS retailPriceMin
    , max(product_varieties.retail_price) AS retailPriceMax
    , avg(product_varieties.retail_price) AS retailPriceAvg
    , COUNT(products.user_id) AS totalUsers
FROM `products`
LEFT JOIN `categories` ON `categories`.`id` = `products`.`category_id`
LEFT JOIN `product_varieties` ON `product_varieties`.`product_id` = `products`.`id`
WHERE `products`.`id` IN (1, 2, 3, 4)
GROUP BY `products`.`category_id`
```

or, depending on the data:

```
    , COUNT(DISTINCT products.user_id) AS totalUsers
```

Answer (score 1):

Your subquery must be correlated, not complete.

```sql
SELECT `categories`.`title`,
         min(product_varieties.wholesale_price) AS wholesalePriceMin,
         max(product_varieties.wholesale_price) AS wholesalePriceMax,
         avg(product_varieties.wholesale_price) AS wholesalePriceAvg,
         min(product_varieties.retail_price) AS retailPriceMin,
         max(product_varieties.retail_price) AS retailPriceMax,
         avg(product_varieties.retail_price) AS retailPriceAvg,
         
    (SELECT COUNT(p.user_id)
    FROM products p
    WHERE p.user_id = `products`.user_id) AS totalUsers
FROM `products`
LEFT JOIN `categories`
    ON `categories`.`id` = `products`.`category_id`
LEFT JOIN `product_varieties`
    ON `product_varieties`.`product_id` = `products`.`id`
WHERE `products`.`id` IN (1,2,3,4)
GROUP BY  `products`.`category_id`
```

PS. Maybe, `COUNT(DISTINCT p.user_id)` needed...